# CP Edit Columns only possible for admins?

Tags: control-panel, craft4

I just found out that non-admin users can't edit the columns shown for the entries. Is there a way to activate this for non-admin users as well?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Brandon Kelly wrote a tweet on that:

> Just wrapped up a pretty cool feature for Craft 4.3 – the ability for users to customize the visible table columns on element indexes. The project config only stores the default column now.

https://twitter.com/brandonkelly/status/1569818239198191618

So right now this is not possible, but it should be with Craft 4.3.